# javamail combine html and plain text

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I've seen many answerns in StackOverflow of how to send a mail with both, plain text and html text. My question is, how can I show some kind of link in the html part to see the text part? (something `click here to see plain text` and show the plain text version when clicked)

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for sending a plain text version is to support clients that can't or won't (security) show HTML. If they have already displayed the HTML version they obviously support it, so a link to plain text is not very useful.

What you can easily do is to add the plain text in the HTML and have a link that when clicked hides the formatted version and shows the text in a "plain" version, i.e. a div that only contains text. That gives you the behavior you are looking for.

As far as I know there is no way for the HTML rendered in a mail client to access other parts of the mail, at least not in a portable way.